# How can an existing storage server in Solid Explorer be edited?

Tags: file-management

In Solid Explorer (2.7.7), how can an existing network storage server (e.g. SFTP, LAN/SMB; all grouped by Solid Explorer into "Cloud Storage") be changed? ? How can one be deleted? Holding on the server name in the "Storages" list or the title bar has no affect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tap the "[hamburger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755666/what-is-the-hamburger-menu-icon-called-and-the-three-vertical-dots-icon-called)" icon (☰) to open the sidebar.
2. Tap the vertical ellipses (⋮) to open the menu.
3. Tap "Storage Manager".

From here, tap a storage's menu button to edit or delete the server. Additionally, the storage order can be changed by holding and dragging an item.